# Python Function Return Loop

Tags: python, recursion

Ok, so this piece of code is from a practice question at my school.  We are to mentally parse the code and check the answer.

When I first parsed it, I got 4.  I copied the code and ran it through IDLE and got 8.  I ran the debugger and saw that the else: return is looping the if else statement until `x == 0` and then it returns 1.

I do not understand how return 1 is coming out to 8.

```
def foo(x=5):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2*foo(x-1)

print(foo(3))
```

I understand that it is calling `foo(x-1)` inside the function `foo(x=5)` which makes it check if else again and again until `x == 0` then it returns 1.  How does return 1 end up printing 8?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653496/python-function-return-loop ?

Comment: `foo` is a recursive calculation of "2 to the _x_ power", for non-negative integer values of _x_.  (If it had multiplied `foo(x-1)` by `x` instead of by `2`, it would have calculated "_x_ factorial" instead.)

Comment: @wap26 the link you provided seems to be my question

Comment: @proxenmity it was a recursion joke. You missed it. For explanation, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32653496/2066079

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will make following calls to foo:

```
foo(3) -> foo(2) -> foo(1) -> foo(0)
```

those will return

```
foo(0) -> 1
foo(1) -> 2 * foo(0) -> 2 * 1 -> 2
foo(2) -> 2 * foo(1) -> 2 * 2 -> 4
foo(3) -> 2 * foo(2) -> 2 * 4 -> 8
```

Is it clear now?

Comment: @JamesHaskett: this answer (implicitly) shows a method for implementing the same function without using recursion. It would be a good exercise to implement `foo` both with and without recursion and compare the two approaches.

Answer (score 11):

I think you’re having the right idea (otherwise you wouldn’t have gotten the answer 4), you’re simply aborting too early in your mental exercise.

You can keep track of the variables by tabulating them while going through the code:

- `foo(3)`

  - calls `foo(3 - 1)` → `foo(2)`

    - calls `foo(2 - 1)` → `foo(1)`

      - calls `foo(1 - 1)` → `foo(0)`

        - returns `1`
      - returns `2 * foo(1 - 1)` → `2`
    - returns `2 * foo(2 - 1)` → `4`
  - returns `2 * foo(3 - 1)` → `8`

Answer (score 4):

Recursion works in reverse from what you'd initially expect. It doesn't start with x=3, but instead it follows all the recursive calls and the first value of x is actually 0.

Here is a modified version of your script that illustrates the order of how it ran the steps and how it arrived at 8.

```
def foo(x=5):
    if x == 0:
        r = 1
        print (x, r)
        return r
    else:
        r = 2*foo(x-1)
        print (x, r)
        return r

print(foo(3))
```

Notice how the first value of x that's printed is 1 instead of the 3 you gave it. Once you understand this, you will understand recursion.